# How to save data on a JSON file so data doesn't reset each time my Discord Bot logs off

Tags: javascript, json, save, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that uses a warning system.

Depending on the reason why you were warned, you get "points", when you reach 100 points, you get automatically kicked from the server.

So if Insults is at 15 points and Spam is at 20 points for example :

/warn Sappeur Insults: my warnLevel would be at 15 points

/warn Sappeur Spam: my warnLevel would be at 35 points since I already had 15.

But that data would just reset if the bot happens to go offline, so I need to know how can I get this data to be saved into a JSON file I created called "warnLevel". And please, you're talking to a beginner here, try not to make this too complicated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to a file in the system using

```
writeFile(Path, Data, Callback)
```

its a node.js method from the fsLibrary, but as you are using discord.js you surely are working with node (correct me if im wrong)
Example:

```
 // import fs module in which writeFile function is defined.  
  const fsLibrary  = require('fs')     // Data which will need to add in a file. 
  let data = "Hello world."    // Write data in 'newfile.txt' . 
  fsLibrary.writeFile('newfile.txt', data, (error) => {
 // In case of a error throw err exception. 
     if (error) throw err;  
  })
```

and to read from the file and load the configuration, then you can use the method

```
readFile(Path, Options, Callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried some code with those commands you suggested

```
` switch (args[2]) {
                case 'Freekill': {
                    let data = "20";
                    fs.writeFile('./warnLevel.json', data, (error) => {
                        if (error) throw err;
                    })
                    break;
                }

                case 'Spam' : {
                    let data = "10";
                    fs.writeFile('./warnLevel.json', data, (error) => {
                        if (error) throw err;
                    })
                    break;

                }


            }
            break;
        } `
```

I had two main problems :
1) The command overwrote everything that was already in the json file, I need it to keep track of the different users points, it can't get overwritten everytime
2)When I added the second case, this error happened :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1175
throw err;
^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\PobWarn\warnLevel.json: Unexpected end of JSON            input  
at parse (<anonymous>)
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules         /cjs/loader.js:1172:22)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)?[39m
?[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)?[39m
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\PobWarn\index.js:6:19)
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules                                        /cjs/loader.js:1158:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)?[39m
```

And sorry but I don't think I understood what the readFile command is used for and what should I put in options and callback. Sorry for being a hassle

Comment: You didn't reply to Sebastian like I think you intended, you will have to mention him. Anyways you would need to set the json file to an object, not a number or string. This way you can have more data and less "overwrite", this is pretty simple though and since you didn't understand it I would suggest just learning javascript first before you move on.